# Error : this.state.data[index].number prints index is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, http-delete

I need to use a DELETE request with axios to delete a book from a list. I use this.state.data[index].number to get the number of the book and pass it to the URL but the console prints an error "index is not defined". How can I solve that error?

Otherwise, when I replace index by a specific index like 1, I get the number of the book add to the URL, but my variable cible, which also needs that number to remove the book, prints null...

This is my code :

```
export default class ListBooks extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null, data: [], number: "" }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ data: res.data });
            })
            .catch(errorThrown => {
                this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
            })
    }

        /**
        * Use to delete a book by the id.
        */
        handleDelete = () => {
            const id = this.state.data[index].number           
            Axios.delete(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS + id)
                .then(res => {
                     console.log(res);
                    console.log(res.data);
                    let cible = document.getElementById("book-admin" + id);
                    console.log(cible);
                    cible.remove();
                })
                .catch(errorThrown => {
                    this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
                })
        }

        render() {
            const { data } = this.state;

            return (
                <div>

                    <Container>

                        {data.map((books, index) =>
                            <div key={books.number}>
                                <ListGroup>
                                    <ListGroup.Item disabled id={"book-admin" + data.number}>{books.number}. {books.name} {books.author}
                                    </ListGroup.Item>
                                </ListGroup>
                                <Button variant="outline-warning" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change" id={data.number} onClick={this.props.handleUpdate}>Modifier</Button>
                                <Button variant="outline-danger" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change"  onClick={this.handleDelete}>Supprimer</Button>

                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Container>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: `handleDelete` has no variable or parameter passed to it called `index`, neither is it defined globally inside the class, that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the index.

Try this:

```
onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}
```

and

```
handleDelete = (index) => {
```

---

After sending the delete request if you want to remove that item from your state array you can use this:

```
handleDelete = (index) => {
    const id = this.state.data[index].number
    Axios.delete(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS + id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
            // let cible = document.getElementById("book-admin" + id);
            // console.log(cible);
            // cible.remove();
            this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, data: prevState.data.filter((book) => book.number !== id) }))
        })
        .catch(errorThrown => {
            this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the index as an argument in `handleDelete` function:

```
 handleDelete = (index) => {
            const id = this.state.data[index].number           
            Axios.delete(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS + id)
                .then(res => {
                     console.log(res);
                    console.log(res.data);
                    let cible = document.getElementById("book-admin" + id);
                    console.log(cible);
                    cible.remove();
                })
                .catch(errorThrown => {
                    this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
                })
        }
```

Change your second `Button` onClick function to:
 `onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}`

Answer (score 1):

The console is right, index is not defined in the scope you need it

Do this

```
  <Button variant="outline-danger" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change"  onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}>Supprimer</Button>
```

And receive the parameter in the function

```
handleDelete = (index) => {
```